# How to debug and find variables in twig themes

Tags: view, drupal, themes

I'm trying to create a theme for a drupal web site, but I find it difficult to get variables.
Here is an example:
to get an image form a view I wrote this line

```
row.content['#row']._entity.field_image.entity.uri.value
```

How can we define this path ? even with **vardumper** and **dump** it's not possible to get this information!!
Is there any effective way to determine how variables are structred ?

Comment: usefull article to understand how : https://blog.usejournal.com/getting-drupal-8-field-values-in-twig-22b80cb609bd

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you to use Kint.
You have to add the following code to dump {{ kint(your_variable) }}

Remember that you have to turn on Twig debugging. You can find more information in: https://www.drupal.org/node/1906392

Comment: Kent also is not very effective